# Converting numbers to string in a given string in Swift

Tags: swift, string

I am given a string like 4eysg22yl3kk and my output should be like this:
foureysgtweny-twoylthreekk or if I am given 0123 it should be output as one hundred twenty-three. So basically, as I scan the string, I need to convert numbers to string.
I do not know how to implement this in Swift as I iterate through the string? Any idea?

Comment: `NumberFormatter` has a `spellOut` option, but will take a bit of work as you'll need to extract the numbers yourself [see this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51402470/ios-speech-to-text-conversion-in-number-format/51416871) for some more ideas

Answer (score 0):

You actually have two basic problems.

The first is convert a "number" to "spelt out" value (ie `1` to `one`).  This is actually easy to solve, as `NumberFormatter` has a `spellOut` style property

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
let text = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: 1))
```

which will result in `"one"`, neat.

The other issue though, is how to you separate the numbers from the text?

While I can find any number of solutions for "extract" numbers or characters from a mixed `String`, I can't find one which return both, split on their boundaries, so, based on your input, we'd end up with `["4", "eysg", "22", "yl", "3", "kk"]`.

So, time to role our own...

```
func breakApart(_ text: String, withPattern pattern: String) throws -> [String]? {
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[0-9]+", options: .caseInsensitive)
        var previousRange: Range<String.Index>? = nil
        var parts: [String] = []
        for match in regex.matches(in: text, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.count)) {
            guard let range = Range(match.range, in: text) else {
                return nil
            }
            let part = text[range]
            if let previousRange = previousRange {
                let textRange = Range<String.Index>(uncheckedBounds: (lower: previousRange.upperBound, upper: range.lowerBound))
                parts.append(String(text[textRange]))
            }
            parts.append(String(part))
            previousRange = range
        }
        if let range = previousRange, range.upperBound != text.endIndex {
            let textRange = Range<String.Index>(uncheckedBounds: (lower: range.upperBound, upper: text.endIndex))
            parts.append(String(text[textRange]))
        }
        return parts
    } catch {
    }
    return nil
}
```

Okay, so this is a little "dirty" (IMHO), but I can't seem to think of a better approach, hopefully someone will be kind enough to provide some hints towards one ;)

Basically what it does is uses a regular expression to find all the groups of numbers, it then builds an array, cutting the string apart around the matching boundaries - like I said, it's crude, but it gets the job done.

From there, we just need to map the results, spelling out the numbers as we go...

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
let value = "4eysg22yl3kk"
if let parts = try breakApart(value, withPattern: pattern) {
    let result = parts.map { (part) -> String in
        if let number = Int(part), let text = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: number)) {
            return text
        }
        return part
        }.joined(separator: " ")
    print(result)
}
```

This will end up printing `four eysg twenty-two yl three kk`, if you don't want the spaces, just get rid of `separator` in the `join` function

I did this in Playgrounds, so it probably needs some cleaning up

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my question without dealing with anything extra than converting my String to an array and check char by char. If I found a digit I was saving it in a temp String and as soon as I found out the next char is not digit, I converted my digit to its text.

let inputString = Array(string.lowercased())